# Angular not reading input changes after ajax auto-complete fills multiple fields

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using jquery auto-complete with ajax to automatically fill out 3 input fields ie Product Code, Description and Price. There are two more fields, Quantity and total which are using angular.

My problem is that the two angular fields don't know when the user has used the auto-complete. When you change the quantity it cannot read the price input until you manually change the price.

I have looked at $watch, $apply, ng-change, but time and time again Angular cannot see my out of scope variable from auto-complete.

View it in a Plunker here http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/8g88JUPDjUfvCWupxKyT/
Note: Search for product code starting with 01 in the "Code" input.

Here is my code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
              <link data-require="jquery-ui@1.8.16" data-semver="1.8.16" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
              <script data-require="jquery@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
              <script data-require="jquery-ui@1.8.16" data-semver="1.8.16" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
              <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
              <script src="script.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  $('.code1').autocomplete({
                    source: [{
                      "value": "01-A",
                      "prod_desc1": "Extra Large Elephant",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-A",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-A-BE",
                      "prod_desc1": "Extra Large Elephant Bookends (pair)",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-A-BE",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-A-Q",
                      "prod_desc1": "Extra Large Ele full colour",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-A-Q",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-B",
                      "prod_desc1": "Large Elephant",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-B",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-B-CH",
                      "prod_desc1": "Large Ele - Candle holder",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-B-CH",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-B-PL",
                      "prod_desc1": "Large Ele Stem Plate",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-B-PL",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-BA",
                      "prod_desc1": "XL-Ben Elephant",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-BA",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-BB",
                      "prod_desc1": "DESIGNER ELEPHANT",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-BB",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-BC",
                      "prod_desc1": "Medium-ben's-elephant",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-BC",
                      "image1": ""
                    }, {
                      "value": "01-BD",
                      "prod_desc1": "DESIGNER ELEPHANT",
                      "price1": "20.00",
                      "prod_code1": "01-BD",
                      "image1": ""
                    }],
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function(evt, ui) {
                      // when a product code is selected, populate related fields in this form
                      this.form.prod_desc1.value = ui.item.prod_desc1;
                      this.form.price1.value = ui.item.price1;
                      $("#image1").html(ui.item.image1);




                    }
                  });
                });
              </script>
              <style type="text/css">
                /* style the auto-complete response */

                li.ui-menu-item {
                  font-size: 12px !important;
                }
              </style>
              <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="OrderController" class="row">
                <div class="page-header">
                  <h1>Order Form</h1>
                  <form onsubmit="return false;">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Image</th>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Desc</th>
                          <th>Price</th>
                          <th>Qty</th>
                          <th>Total</th>
                        </tr> 
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <div class="order-image">
                              <span id="image1"></span>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input id="code1" type="text" class="code1 order-code" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input class="order-prod_desc" id="prod_desc1" type="text" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input ng-model="price1" ng-change="change()" class="order-price" id="price1" name="price1" type="number" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input ng-model="quantity1" class="order-price" id="quantity1" type="number" value="" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input class="order-price" id="total1" type="number" value="{{price1 * quantity1}}" step="0.01" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <script>
                var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);



                myApp.controller('OrderController', function($scope) {

                  function change() {
                    alert("a");
                    var scope = angular.element($("#price1")).scope();
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                      scope.price1 = scope;
                    });
                  }

                });
              </script>
              <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the console log ? Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed that but it still does not work. I think it is an angular issue?

Comment: this is not work ? http://screencast.com/t/oSvIOTGn

Comment: Not surprisingly that it doesn't work, the way you mix jQuery and Angular is not going to work well. While you could make it work, I still suggest building the app in Angular way (google Angular for jQuery deverlopers).

Comment: I really don't know enough about angular and jquery to be able to build this. I don't see though why its so tricky for angular to see a harmless input field? Sure $apply or $watch? but how on earth do i implement them into the jquery auto complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you need to access the model of the fields not the fields it self, you need to get a handle on the input fields model, modify it and then apply those changes how to do that? actually simple

```
function jqueryAutoCompleteHandler(){
// other stuff
  var angularElement=angular.element(element);
  var scope = angularElement.scope();
  var parser = angularElement.injector().get('$parse');
  var getter = parser(angularElement.attr('ng-model'));
  var setter = getter.assign;
  setter(scope, value) 
  scope.$apply();
}
```

something like this should work. little variations and spellcheck might be needed. but thats the general idea.
check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XB7t3sePl3QbkopOoR3U?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the function. Though I am not sure where I put it or what variations it needs? I just dumped it on to my page but the script does the same.

Comment: I hope this works as i have not used plunker before http://plnkr.co/edit/XdGjHy?p=preview

Comment: check the updates in the response there is a link to a new plunker there hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much it works! I'm new to angular and jquery. Would you say, on the whole, Is this script bad practice? I mean mixing jquery and Angular this way?

Comment: sometimes there is no other choice, in your case i would have use an angular service and a directives to autocomplete my form. in this case i wouldn't mix, in general if i have an angular project from scratch never use jquery.  the only reason for me to intermix have been when dealing with mixed projects